# Using an alternative to a Python Module when you wish to create derived Singletons

Tags: python, design-patterns, inheritance, singleton

In a Python project I need to provide a user with a single instance of various concepts, lets call them 'dog', 'cat' and 'parrot'. There is some functionality that they share, like sleep(), eat() and is_dead(), that I would like to place into the concept 'pet' for the purposes of code reuse. There can be multiple pets, but there is only ever one pet of each type.

I believe it is not possible to have a Python module inherit from another module, therefore if I wanted to use just modules I would have to throw out the 'pet' concept and have repeated code (sleep, eat, etc) in each of the 'dog', 'cat' and 'parrot' modules. Or create a 'pet' module and then use 'from pet import *' in each of the other modules, which as far as I am aware is considered bad practice.

Alternatively I could create a 'pet' class (derived from a Singleton-implementing base class), and then derive 'dog', 'cat' and 'parrot' classes from that. However I see that most discussion of the Singleton pattern in Python imply that the pattern is not a good idea.

So, I want to avoid three areas that I get the impression are bad practice:

- Code replication between different source files
- The use of 'from x import *'
- The use of the Singleton design pattern

However I cannot achieve all three with any of the solutions above. I am tempted to go with the Singleton design-pattern as it seems the 'least bad' option. Is there a way to achieve what I want while avoiding all three problems and without introducing any other bad practice?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell with your examples, but do these actually need to be separate instances? Could they be classmethods on a shared Animal superclass?

Comment: Why not create instances of a shared class? `dog = Pet(...)` is then a global in a module. You can alway attach additional functions to that instance.

Comment: While `from pet import *` would be recommended against, `from pet import dog, cat, parrot` is **not**.

Comment: Yes, @MartijnPieters's comment is what I thought.  Please, user1472525, elaborate on why you cannot just make instances for dog, cat, parrot from one pet class.

Comment: In my experience, most people reaching for Singletons are over-engineering their problem. In Python, it is *not your problem* if someone shoots themselves in the foot by creating more than one instance of your singleton classes. Just create `Pet`, `Cat`, `Dog` and `Parrot` classes, create one instance of the latter three each, and document your API as using those instances. Using `del Cat, Dog, Parrot` if you have to right after creating the instances to prevent easy importing is usually all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. @Martjin @Alfe : I cannot see a reason why I couldn't do that, I just hadn't thought that way. If I understand instead of a `class Dog(Pet):` declaration I would call `dog = Pet()` and then 'monkey patch' (?) dog-specific methods afterwards. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The application: A package that allows a user to write Python scripts that act with a specific GUI. So the user imports the package and then writes something like `pkg.pages.first_page.click_button(pkg.pages.first_page.SECOND_PAGE)` or `first_page = pkg.pages.first_page.Page()` then `first_page.click_button(first_page.SECOND_PAGE")`. Each of the pages will have a `click_button` method, but they will all contain different buttons that can be clicked. So, a `Page` class with `FirstPage(Page)` etc, and there is only one instance of a page in reality, so why waste memory with more.

Comment: Yes, or make subclasses from Pet and use just the classes instead of instances. @classmethod is your friend then.

Comment: There appears to be a misunderstanding of what you can and cannot inherit from another module. if you import pet`, you can then do class Dog(Pet): and as far as I can see you achieve what you want (minus guaranteeing single instance of Dog). Dogs will have the sleep(), eat() methods of Pets, and can be given a Bark() method in the class definition. No monkeypatching.

Comment: ... and you can check if there is more than one Dog in the Dog's constructor...

Comment: … or simply use just the Dog class itself instead of an instance.

Comment: With a little playing around with these suggestions, I have realised that using just classes and classmethods, as suggested by @Daniel (and then Alfe who I can't notify with an '@'), is the most appropriate solution. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to move away from thinking about instances of classes as the only way to produce inheritance structures that can be interacted with: it is possible to create classes with classmethods (not just instance methods).

Therefore the inheritance structure can be created as desired, with `Dog`, `Cat` and `Parrot` inheriting from `Pet`. Then, by using classmethods instead of instance methods, those classes can be interacted with without instantiation, and so without any need of the Singleton pattern. If there is any state required this can be held at class level with class attributes.

The use of classmethods is well documented [elsewhere](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Example:

```
class Pet(object):
    @classmethod
    def is_dead(cls):
        return False

class Dog(Pet):
    @classmethod
    def bark(cls):
        print "woof"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not Dog.is_dead():
        Dog.bark()
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I believe it is not possible to have a Python module inherit from another module

I'm not sure what you meant by this - it seems like the problem you have is one of simple class inheritance, which you would naturally do using another module:

file: pet.py

```
class Pet():
  def __init__(self):
      self._type = "Generic pet"

  def sleep(self):
      print self.type, "is sleeping"
```

file dog.py

```
import pet

class Dog(pet.Pet):
       number_of_dogs = 0

       def __init__(self):
          if (Dog.number_of_dogs != 0):
               raise Exception("Grrrr...")
          pet.Pet.__init__(self)   # assuming no diamond inheritance of animals
          self.type = "The Dog"
          Dog.number_of_dogs = 1

       def Bark(self):
          print "Woof"
```

prompt> python

```
>>> import pet
>>> import dog
>>> c = dog.Dog()
>>> d = dog.Dog()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dog.py", line 8, in __init__
    raise Exception("Grrrr...")
Exception: Grrrr...
>>> c.sleep()
The Dog is sleeping
>>> c.Bark()
Woof
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd follow some well written tutorials and combine ["sharing global variables across modules"](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm) with ["inheritance"](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html#inheritance)